# How to permanently mount a network folder?

Tags: networking, mount, fstab

I have followed the [wiki on this topic](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) and applied this [solution](https://whereofwecannotspeak.wordpress.com/2007/12/25/unmount-samba-filesystems-before-shutdown-or-reboot/) to fix the hang on shutdown and referred to a few other posts on here but can't get a Synology folder (Windows share) to mount on boot in Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried both these in my fstab:

```
//serverip/foldername /mnt/foldername cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0

//serverip/foldername /mnt/foldername cifs _netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0600,nounix,forceuid,forcegid,credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

`sudo mount -a` works in terminal so I assume the details are correct.

Is this a bug with the boot order in Ubuntu? Does fstab stuff get run before the network interface is loaded? I am connected over wifi if that makes any difference. I don't have home encryption on either.

Answer (score 1):

From the `Mount during login instead of boot` section of the wiki link you posted, perhaps try adding this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  noauto,credentials=/home/ubuntuusername/.smbpasswd  0  0
```

And this to your `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
mount /media/windowsshare
exit 0
```

Comment: I think the `mount` is not needed because all folders in the fstab are being mounted automatically

Comment: The mount is needed because the fstab entry specifies "noauto"